# Linux reboot system utility and c library function difference

Tags: c, linux

Is there any difference between **reboot** linux utility and c library function functionality wise?

Comment: Every single difference the VFS affords.

Answer (score 0):

The utility also does at least a `sync()` and a short sleep to ensure disk caches get flushed.

I failed to find the source for Linux's reboot command with a quick google, but here's OpenBSD's version: http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/OpenBSD/src/sbin/reboot/reboot.c